# Regular Expression PatternSyntaxException error

Tags: java, regex

I'm not sure why the following is giving me a `PatternSyntaxException`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\[[12|\\[|\\|\\||\\^\\^|\\^|\\_|\\_\\_|\\=|abcdefgABCDEFG|\\|");
```

It claims the error is at `|a` which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a matching ']' to the one that isn't escaped...

```
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\[[12|...
                                     |This one
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the characters inside the unescaped pipes supped to be a character range? Of so, they should be in square brackets.

```
[A-Ga-g]
```

It's an error because the pipe character is a regex logical operator (or).